# WP: How to change text from title to date for each different post in archive on hover with HTML/CSS?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, hover

I'm a complete noob, trying to learn HTML/CSS while struggling to make my website do what I want it to …

Using `<?php wp_get_archive('type=alpha') ?>`, I'm trying to make the title of each post/row in the archive change to display the date of each post (with permalink to the post), instead of the whole `<li>` change to just the date of the first post (without permalink) …

What I have right now is this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="date">
    <div class="date-text"><?php the_date('y.m.d'); ?></div>
    <div class="arc"><?php wp_get_archives('type=alpha'); ?></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.date-text {
    display: none;
}
.date:hover .date-text {
    display: inline;
}
.date:hover .arc {
    display: none;
}
```

But the `<?php wp_get_archive('type=alpha') ?>` creates the following HTML output:

```
<div class="arc">
    <li><a href='url_four'>four</a></li>
    <li><a href="url_one">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="url_three">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="url_two">two</a></li>
</div>
```

I want it to do something along the lines of placing each `<li>` in its own `<div class="arc">` so that each url gets replaced by its respective date, and not all of them end up in the same `<div>` to be replaced by `<div class="date-text">`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "… Which obviously won't do." Why not, whats not working?

Comment: When I hover on any of the entries in the archive, the whole list changes to display only the date of the first entry. I want each entry to display a different date on hovering, and I want the date to be a permalink to the entry.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. Are you sure your php is geting the right values?
If I got you wrong send a sample what the list should look like as my english ist not the best.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Unbenanntes Dokument</title>
<style>
.date-text {
    display: none;
}
.date:hover .date-text {
    display: inline;
}
.date:hover .arc {
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="date">
        <div class="date-text">date1</div>
        <div class="arc">text 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
        <div class="date-text">date2</div>
        <div class="arc">text 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
        <div class="date-text">date3</div>
        <div class="arc">text 3</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

try something like:

    `<?php
    $alpha = wp_get_archive('type=alpha');
    $date = the_date('y.m.d'); 
    echo'<div class="date">';
        echo'<div class="date-text">' . $date .'</div>';
        echo'<div class="arc">'. $alpha.'</div>';
    echo'</div>';`
    ?>